Как использовать данные из main.py в routes в aiogram 3.x?
Возможно простой вопрос, но ранее с таким никогда не сталкивался, ибо сейчас первый раз принялся писать масштабный проект, где нужно делить всего бота на части.
Суть вопроса заключается в том, что у меня есть класс Database, который представляет собой обьект для упрощения взаимодействия с моей базой данных SQLite. В нем находится ряд методов для добавления/удаления/изменения данных. Я столкнулся с тем, что мне нужно создать один экземпляр класса Database в основном файле и уже именно этот экземпляр передавать каким либо образом в Routes, для того что бы не возникало конфликтов из за одновременных обращений к БД из-за наличия множества отдельных экземпляров класса Database.
Временно решил эту проблему используя библиотеку contextvars, создав отдельный файл context.py где создаются переменные контекста, а уже в main.py записываю в контекст экземпляр своего класса.
Хотелось бы узнать как вообще решать подобные проблемы, насколько правильно решил проблему

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Вы можете любые объекты передавать в свой Dispatcher при старте пулинга
